# UIActionSheet Like Button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How could I create a button that looks like the button in a UIActionSheet, as apple have done sometimes in their apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Jeff LaMarche's blog for both description and code:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/improved-gradient-buttons.html

Code project here:
http://code.google.com/p/iphonegradientbuttons/

Answer (score 0):

Matt Gemmell's [MGImageUtilities](http://github.com/mattgemmell/MGImageUtilities) may be of use also.